# Looking for a way to programmatically trigger Android ActionBar home so it goes into pressed state

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am developing a fly-in menu feature. Its working well - except for a visual touch I am trying to add.

As with the Google+ app, when the user clicks anywhere on the open pane, it closes. I would like to show the Home button in its pressed state when the pane is closed this way. Ideally, I could just performClick the Home button, but I do not see an obvious way to access the ActionBar's views.

Answer (score 2):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10187523/actionbarsherlock-how-to-access-home-button-view) the home button in the `ActionBar` is not contained in the `Activity` content view, but belongs to the decoration.

With the following code

```
mActivity.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.home);
```

I retrieve the home button and then I click on it

Answer (score 0):

you can work with `actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable`, then use `findViewById` to get the home button and set him manually to pressed mode `Button.setPressed(true)`

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about this? How does `setBackgroundDrawable` help?