# Sherlock Action Bar : findViewById(android.R.id.home) return null in android 2.3

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using Sherlock Action Bar for my project. But I face on problem. I am using this code in OnCreate method.

```
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    View iconImage = findViewById(android.R.id.home);
    iconImage.setPadding(100, 0, 0, 0);
```

In android 4.1 the "iconImage" is not null. But on android 2.3. iconImage is always null.
Do you know why? and Do you know how can I get home button in android 2.3. 
Note : I checked , I can detect home button click action by implement onOptionsItemSelected method.

Please help me !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"You cannot access the home view because it exists above the content view and in the window decoration"

See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10187523/actionbarsherlock-how-to-access-home-button-view) by the author of ActionBarSherlock

P/s: VNese :D

Comment: thank Wayne. Yes I am VNese :) Are you too ?
I am a newbie in Action Bar Sherlock (Android too). Follow your link. I think I should customize Home button. But do you know how can I add android:padding to home button. I am already customize action bar. But I don't know how can I add padding to home icon

Comment: I customize action bar like this : <style name="Widget.MyCustom.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="background">@drawable/action_bar_bg</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_bar_bg</item>
        <item name="icon">@drawable/back_button_bg</item>
        <item name="android:icon">@drawable/back_button_bg</item>
    </style>

Comment: You set your "home button" by using actionbar.setIcon(R.drawable.home_icon), right? If so, why don't you add padding to home_icon image? 
P/S: yes, i'm vnese too :D

Comment: Thank Wayne very much. Follow your advise I used <layer-list/> to add padding to home icon, it work well. But I get another problem. When user press on home button, it's highlight look bad. The icon is not center when it is highlighted. Do you have any idea to fix it ?