# Actionbarsherlock custom layout clickable imageview

Tags: android, imageview, actionbarsherlock, clickable

I am trying to make my imageview that is defined in my custom layout for Actionbarsherlock clickable. My activity first sets a layout:

```
setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);
```

The actionbar_layout is set in the same activity like this:

```
View cView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.actionbar_layout,
            null);
    actionBar.setCustomView(cView);
```

The actual actionbar_layout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="left"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/actionBarLogo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="50dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="50dp"
    android:paddingTop="50dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Adding this:

```
actionBarLogo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //code 
        }
    });
```

Results in a Nullpointer exception for this line:

```
actionBarLogo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
```

The custom layout works fine, i just need the imageview to be clickable. 
Any ideas how to fix this? 
How can my activity get a reference to my actionBarLogo id which is defined in actionbar_layout.xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
//your code
View cView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.actionbar_layout,
        null);
actionBar.setCustomView(cView);

ImageView actionBarLogo = (ImageView) cView.findViewById(R.id.actionBarLogo);

actionBarLogo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //code 
    }
});
```

It should work.

Answer (score 2):

Use ImageButton insteadOf ImageView

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/actionBarLogo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="50dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="50dp"
    android:paddingTop="50dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:onClick="somemethod"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />
```

Comment: That works aswell.. cannot upvote though (not enough reputation)

Answer (score 0):

as far as i understand your problem, its not possible to access the desired view, because its not part of the view or part of the window decoration. Check this post here, to find a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10187801/1965084

Comment: Cheers alex, i was afraid of this. Waiting a little more time for a possible other answer before setting yours as accepted.