# Add Button to Action Bar Sherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I've been working to try and create a custom ABS layout to no avail. Basically, I'm trying to add a button to the menu which will do something when clicked (right now, it just says "Successfully clicked". Here is my implementation:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

    ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setTitle("Main Screen");
    bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0000FF")));

    View cView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_action_bar, null);
    bar.setCustomView(cView);
    ImageView actionBarLogo = (ImageView) cView.findViewById(R.id.actionBarLogo);

    actionBarLogo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Toast.makeText(DashboardActivity.this.getApplicationContext(),"Successfully clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

And here's my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/actionBarLogo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="50dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="50dp"
    android:paddingTop="50dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/harddisk"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

There is a solution located here: [Actionbarsherlock custom layout clickable imageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629540/actionbarsherlock-custom-layout-clickable-imageview)
that I've tried, but the button still does not show up in the action bar. Any ideas?