# How to use calabash android with a view from the ActionBar Sherlock?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, calabash

I am using calabash in my Androi project. And I want to press a menu item in the Action Bar Sherlock. This view is an icon, its id is R.drawable.info_icon.

If it was a commom view of my layout I could use

```
step 'I press view with id "info_icon"'
```

But with the sherlock I get this error:

```
Step unsuccessful: Could not find view with id: 'info_icon' (RuntimeError)
```

Someone know how can I press this view with my calabash test?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The id you are referring to is that of the image, not that of the view.
Actually, any view within the ActionBar is not accessible to you, as explained by the [creator of the library himself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10187523/actionbarsherlock-how-to-access-home-button-view).

Instead, you can try to touch the view based on its index.  To find the index, check out [this tutorial](http://blog.lesspainful.com/2012/12/18/Android-Query/) which shows how to use a real-time console to discover the view. Once you have a good query of the element you want to touch, simply write a custom step as following:

```
When /^I press the info icon menu item$/ do 
  macro 'I press the menu key'
  wait_for_elements_exist(["IconMenuItemView index:X"])
  touch("IconMenuItemView index:X")
end
```

X being the index of the view you found using the console.